# interpolate previous day values using pandas

Tags: pandas

I use `ffill` to interpolate previous values but what if the whole day missing values in column b but not in column a, can I fill them with the previous day values by keeping the same structure like shown below?

input

```
datetime  a b
2020-01-01 00:00:00  10 20
2020-01-01 01:00:00  15 30
2020-01-01 03:00:00  16 40
2020-01-01 04:00:00  17 50
2020-01-01 05:00:00  15 60
2020-01-02 00:00:00  10 0
2020-01-02 01:00:00  15 0
2020-01-02 03:00:00  16 0
2020-01-02 04:00:00  17 0
2020-01-02 05:00:00  15 0
2020-01-03 00:00:00  10 10
2020-01-03 01:00:00  15 0
2020-01-03 03:00:00  16 0
2020-01-03 04:00:00  17 0
2020-01-03 05:00:00  15 0
```

output

```
datetime  a b
2020-01-01 00:00:00  10 20
2020-01-01 01:00:00  15 30
2020-01-01 03:00:00  16 40
2020-01-01 04:00:00  17 50
2020-01-01 05:00:00  15 60
2020-01-02 00:00:00  10 20
2020-01-02 01:00:00  15 30
2020-01-02 03:00:00  16 40
2020-01-02 04:00:00  17 50
2020-01-02 05:00:00  15 60
2020-01-03 00:00:00  10 10
2020-01-03 01:00:00  15 0
2020-01-03 03:00:00  16 0
2020-01-03 04:00:00  17 0
2020-01-03 05:00:00  15 0
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean b not in a

Comment: I meant column a and column b.

Comment: So you want to fill `b` based on `a` value?

Comment: Is it correct that `2020-01-02 00:00:00` occurs twice in your dataframe with the same value for `a`? This can make solutions more complicated.

Comment: @Scoot No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Quang: yes that's right.

Comment: Sorry meant `2020-01-02 00:00:00`

Comment: Then I'm curious as to why last few rows weren't updated? Didn't you say you wanted `ffill`?

Comment: Because I only want to fill days with all zeroes. For example, `2020-01-02` has all zeroes but not `2020-01-03`

Comment: As far I can tell, `2020-01-02` does not have all zero (last line of the day), `2020-01-03` does. :-)

Comment: Oops. sorry. That's a mistake. I fixed it.